# Update a session with Google Fit REST API

Tags: google-fit

I can create successfully sessions with the [Fit REST API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions/update).
But when I try to update one (ie change the name), it creates a new session, even if I use the previously created session ID in the url and in the request body (I do the exact same request as the session creation but I change only the "name" property's value).

The result is that I have 2 sessions with the same ID.

If I try to delete the session and the "copy", I get a response error with the message "Session already deleted".

Is there any way to correctly update a session?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/) about `Users.sessions`. You need to use the [`update`](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions/update) method which updates or inserts a given session.

HTTP request:

`PUT https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/userId/sessions/sessionId`

Check the example and explanations [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/using-sessions).

Comment: Unfortunalty, it is exactly what I already done. I also tried queries with [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/fitness/fitness/v1/fitness.users.sessions.update) but I still get a new session created when I try to update an existing one...